# Updating several table columns based off a Select Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

So this is my Select Query called [qryHoursSUM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgsPI.jpg).

```
SELECT DAL.Project
, DAL.Unit
, DAL.Activity
, Sum(([EndTime]-[StartTime])*24) AS Hours
FROM DAL INNER JOIN UnitTbl 
ON (DAL.Project=UnitTbl.Project) AND (UnitTbl.Unit=DAL.Unit)
GROUP BY DAL.Project, DAL.Unit, DAL.Activity;
```

I'm trying to get it to update to the corresponding `*** Actual` field and matching row in my Table called  [UnitTbl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfVaL.jpg), which has the `Project` and `Unit` fields as a composite primary key. I cant seem to get it to work. I've first tried running a update query based on the select query but received an "Operation must use an updateable query", and found out that its not possible. I've made a make table query call qrySumHoursTbl to turn the qryHoursSUM into a table

```
SELECT qryHoursSUM.* INTO SumHoursTbl
FROM qryHoursSUM;
```

Then created an update query called qryUpdateUnitTbl to just update the `002 Actual` field

```
UPDATE SumHoursTbl INNER JOIN UnitTbl 
ON (SumHoursTbl.Unit = UnitTbl.Unit) 
AND (SumHoursTbl.Project = UnitTbl.Project) 
SET UnitTbl.[002 Actual] = [Hours]
WHERE (([Activity]="002 Drafting Submittals"));
```

Is it possible to have an update query to update multiple fields at once or would I have to make a update for each field i want to update?

<strike>Also, for some reason it only update the UnitTbl with whole numbers only, I need to have it show up to 2 decimal places.</strike> After working with so many copies, I completely forgot to change the field size to double. After changing that, its showing up to 2 decimal places

My end goal is to be able to let a user click on a button that shows a variance report of hours for each units Budgeted hours and Actual hours (which would be `[*** Budget]` - `[*** Actual]`) Any tips for things to consider along the way to get there is appreciated, I've trying to figure this out for a week now.

Comment: On your update query do you have Unique Records checked in the query porperties?

Comment: Unique records is set up No on the update query